# How to use sqlcmd GO batch delimiter in DBeaver?

Tags: t-sql, sqlcmd, dbeaver

I need to use GO [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go) delimenters in DBeaver IDE.

I got errors if I do not use GO batch delimeters:

> 'CREATE TRIGGER' must be the first statement in a query batch.

So batch GO delimeters must stay in the script. Cannot be removed or replaced by ' ; '

**How to use sqlcmd with DBeaver IDE?**

```
- OS: Ubuntu 16.94 LTS
- Dbeaver 4.2.3
- sqlcmd: Already installed and avialable in PATH
```

Documentation:
[SQL Server Utilities Statements - GO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found answer for my question:

If we want execute statement

1. Select statements to execute
2. CTRL + ENTER

If we want to execute SQL Script **(which works with GO)**:

1. Select statements to execute
2. ALT + X

Execute SQL statement with result separated in tabs:

1. Select statements to execute
2. ALT + \

Execute SQL Script with result separated in tabs **(which works with GO)**:

1. Select statements to execute
2. CTRL + ALT + X

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your connection and select Edit Connection.

Under SQL Editor -> SQL Processing, click the checkbox for "Datasource  settings" and then change the "Statements delimiter" to **GO**.

Repeat this for each connection. Alternatively you could set this globally (click "Global settings" in the top right of the SQL Processing configuration window), but I wouldn't suggest that unless you ONLY use SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still got same error with this option.