# DBeaver - Statement Terminator not OK?

Tags: t-sql, dbeaver, declare, scalar, terminator

Am using a `DECLARE` and `SET` statement to define @end_dt as `CAST(`...) but, in DBeaver if i end my `DECLARE` statement, and my `SET` statements with an `;` it treats those statements as if separate from the following main query and gives me a scalar variable error. Once I remove the statement terminators (`;`) then it runs.

This is my first month using DBeaver. Is there a setting that allows use of statement terminators smoothly?

Comment: Can you show the code?  Also, which RDBMS are you using?  There are a couple that `tsql` would apply to.

Comment: I suspect that instead of treating the semi-colons (`;`) as a statement terminator, DBeaver is incorrectly treating them as a batch separator (which in Microsoft products, would be `GO`).

Comment: @squillman Edited post to include script text. Using Microsoft SQL Server (Azure). MM 202205120943

Comment: Perhaps relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46976025/how-to-use-sqlcmd-go-batch-delimiter-in-dbeaver